# jquery html not passing back to html variable within getJSON function scope issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
    html += '<ul>';
    var url = '/jr/public/ajax/stories.php?storyId=' + data.storyId + '&type=comments' ;        
    jQuery.getJSON(url,function(datum){                     
        jQuery.each(datum,function(i,elm){
            html += '<li><div class="c-thumb">';
            html += '<img alt="" src="'+elm.thumbImageUrl+'"/>';
            html += '<div class="c-text">';
            html += '<h6><a href="">'+elm.userName+'</a> - '+elm.dateStamp+'</h6>';
            html += '<p>' + elm.commentContent+'</p>';
            html += '</div></li>';      
        });
    });     
    html += '</ul>';
```

The `html` variable is not adding the content from the `getJSON` function to the html variable set outside the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getJSON` function returns **immediately**. That's because the first `A` letter from the `AJAX` acronym means asynchronous. The request is sent and when the server completes the processing, the callback gets executed.

So, it is only **inside** this callback that you can use the `html` variable.

```
var url = '/jr/public/ajax/stories.php';
jQuery.getJSON(url, { storyId: data.storyId, type: 'comments' }, function(datum) {                     
    var html = '<ul>';
    jQuery.each(datum,function(i,elm){
        html += '<li><div class="c-thumb">';
        html += '<img alt="" src="'+elm.thumbImageUrl+'"/>';
        html += '<div class="c-text">';
        html += '<h6><a href="">'+elm.userName+'</a> - '+elm.dateStamp+'</h6>';
        html += '<p>' + elm.commentContent+'</p>';
        html += '</div></li>';      
    });

    html += '</ul>';
    // Here and only here use the html variable. For example you could update the
    // DOM with the value of this variable
});
```

Comment: OK. What should I use instead? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You should use the `html` variable only **inside** the success callback of your AJAX request, not outside it. That simply stems from the very nature of how AJAX works.